# Adding the status of a service to a label .NET

Tags: c#

I have added and installed a service and I'm trying to get the status of the service into a label e.g. "running".
I have added the following code

```
public ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
lblServices.Text = sc.Status.ToString();
```

However I'm getting the following run-time error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.ServiceProcess.dll

Additional information: Service name  contains invalid characters, is empty, or is too long (max length = 80)."

Comment: what is the name of the service that you want to get the status for?

Comment: It's called "MyService"

Comment: Yeah. Lets do some logic. Your code and the error - where exactly did you set the name of the service? What does the error say? Oh, the service name is empty (possibly). Matches with you not doing any configuration on the service controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the service in the constructor of `ServiceController` like this:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService");
lblServices.Text = sc.Status.ToString();
```

Or via the `ServiceName` property like this:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "MyService";
lblServices.Text = sc.Status.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for that you got it in one :)